# Expanding left binder in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand monads in Haskell so I am reading https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads

Let's consider a piece of code from above site:

```
maternalGrandfather :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
maternalGrandfather s = (return s) >>= mother >>= father

fathersMaternalGrandmother :: Sheep -> Maybe Sheep
fathersMaternalGrandmother s = (return s) >>= father >>= mother >>= mother
```

And everything is clear. But I wonder how to make a long ( perhaps infinite ) sequence. I mean for example:

```
expand :: Int -> Sheep -> MaybeSheep
```

and for example expand for `expand 10 s` makes `(return s) >>= father >>= father >>= father >>= father >>= father .. ( 10 times)`

How to implement it. Maybe expanding using recursion but I cannot imagine what can be returned on stop.

Comment: An *infinite* sequence of monadic actions will *never* return. The `(>>=)` operator is too strict for that.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid This is not true in general, the operational semantics of `>>=` depend entirely on how the function is defined for any particular monad. e.g `fix (\x -> x : [[1]] >>= scanl (+) 1)` is perfectly well-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of thinking about how to apply a "monadic function" repeatedly to a monadic value, let's think instead about how to "collapse" a list of monadic functions into a single function that can be later applied to the monadic value.

In Haskell, the archetypal combinator that "collapses" lists is called [`foldr`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.11/base-4.8.2.0/Prelude.html#v:foldr):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

`foldr` receives a *function*, an *initial value*, and a *list* as arguments. What it does is to substitute every constructor `:` of the list with the function, and the empty constructor `[]` at the end of the list with the initial value. For example, consider the following list of ints:

```
4 : 5 : 77 : 34 : []
```

Assume we want to add all the elements of the list to 88. We can do it like this

```
foldr (+) 88 (4 : 5 : 77 : 34 : [])
```

which is really equal to

```
4 + 5 + 77 + 34 + 88.
```

Ok, now imagine that the elements of the list are functions of type `a -> a`. We can combine two functions with the composition operator `(.)` but, with what function shall we substitute the end of the list `[]`? We don't want to add any further modification, so we put the "neutral element" for composition, the identity function `id`:

```
 foldr (.) id ((\x -> x + 1) : (\y -> y + 2) : [])
```

This is equal to

```
 (\x -> x + 1) . (\y -> y + 2) . id
```

We are getting closer. We need a composition operator like `(.)` but for monadic functions, that can combine two monadic functions and produce another. Something of type `Monad m => (a -> m a) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a`. [Looking for the signature in Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/lts-5.11/hoogle?q=Monad%20m%20%3D%3E%20%28a%20-%3E%20m%20a%29%20-%3E%20%28a%20-%3E%20m%20a%29%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20m%20a), we find the slightly more general (but still appropriate) operator [`(<=<)`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.11/base-4.8.2.0/Control-Monad.html#v:-60--61--60-):

```
 (<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
```

There's only one detail left: what is the "identity" for monadic function composition? Well, it is `return`, that puts a pure value in a "neutral" monadic context. In the case of `Maybe`, `return` is simply the `Just` constructor.

So, in conclusion: if you want to combine a list of monadic functions, you can do it like this:

```
  combineMonadicFunctions :: Monad m => [a -> m a] -> a -> m a
  combineMonadicFunctions fs = foldr (<=<) return fs
```

And now you can apply the result to the original monadic value using `(>>=)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using iterate

```
iterate (>>= father) (return s) !! 10
```

Change 10 to the number of desired applications of father.

Comment: ok, it is not general. What about I have a list and my stop constraint is []

Comment: @Gilgamesz - You can always use `find` to add a stop constraint.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list on monadic actions (e.g., `[IO x]` or `[Maybe Int]` or something), you can use the `sequence` function to chain all those actions together. (Notice that they all have to have identical types to put them in a list in the first place.)

If you have a list of inputs and you want to pass them to a monadic function (e.g., `String -> Maybe Int`), you can `map` your function over the list, resulting in a list of monadic actions. You can then use `sequence` to chain those. But that's a common pattern, so there's a function for that: you can use `mapM` directly for that case.

In general, have a poke around in `Control.Monad` to see what other helpful monad-related functions are around.